# Failed to launch Remote Desktop Extension server (Unknown Status 0x80BB0001) . Fail To Start Vbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am getting below error while starting My vm. I have installed RDP server in this vm.
Error: Failed to launch Remote Desktop Extension server (Unknown Status 0x80BB0001).
Any help will be appreciate.
Complete Error Details:

> ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={3295e6ce-b051-47b2-9514-2c588bfe7554} aComponent={ExtPackManager} aText={No extension pack by the name 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' was found}, preserve=false
>
> VRDE: Failed: (Unknown Status 0x80BB0001), error message: 'Failed to launch Remote Desktop Extension server (Unknown Status 0x80BB0001)'
>
> ERROR [COM]: aRC=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) aIID={1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb} aComponent={Console} aText={Failed to launch Remote Desktop Extension server (Unknown Status 0x80BB0001)}, preserve=false
>
> Power up failed (vrc=Unknown Status 0x80BB0001, rc=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005))

Answer (score 0):

The best place to get help is to post these kind of topics on virtualbox forum itself. This is the solution `https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=45181` that showed up on virtualbox with the error code that you posted here. This might not be the exact solution you might be looking for. I haven't read all the details, but you might be interested there. Few googling with the error code won't hurt either.

Comment: I have just added complete error details. Please take a look on that.